# How to revert a commit and create a new branch from those changes?

Tags: git

Its late Sunday and I made a bad mistake. I commited and pushed directly into the master branch, where I should have created a branch and pushed the changes to the new branch instead.

So I could do a `git revert SHA` to revert the last commit with a new commit.

However how about my changes, I don't want to loose them.

Shall I create a branch from already modified Master like `git checkout -b feature` and then revert the Master branch?

But what happens once I merge back feature into master, will it know that that commit was reverted on Master previously and eliminate it? `git merge feature`

Btw, there is no history rewriting problem, as I'm the only developer working on this project. Hence I would consider a hard reset, if its the better choice.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are the only developer, then you can do a hard reset. If `abc123` is the SHA1 of the accidental commit, then do:

```
git checkout master
git branch feature-branch
git reset --hard abc123^
```

This will keep your new commit in the new `feature-branch` branch (without switching to that new branch yet), and then rewind `master` back to the previous commit. Then you can push the corrected `master` branch using `git push -f origin master`.

Answer (score 0):

### A generalized version of the above answer, revert back to any commit in time while keeping latest code in new branch

I had this issue many times.

First, use the `git log` command to find the commit SHA you want to revert to.

Once you got that, follow these commands in order (use `main` instead of master depending on your repo):

```
1. git checkout master
2. git branch dev-changes
3. git reset --hard commit_hash_before_your_changes

4. git push origin master --force

5. git checkout dev-changes
6. git push origin dev-changes
```

This way you can revert your master branch back to a commit you want, while keeping your commits afterward on a new branch.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But this is identical to the already existing accepted answer.

Comment: No, the difference is that the accepted answer only works when you have one wrong commit (`bad_commit^`) this way you can restore to any point in time while preserving all the commits afterwards. And I also tell the command to check the commit history which honestly I didn't know when I started using Git

Comment: But the OP wanted to go back one and didn't need to check the history, so the accepted answer is right. You need to differentiate yours so it doesn't seem like mere repetition. Maybe you could edit to explain that this is a generalized version of the accepted answer.

Comment: Added a heading at the top.